# DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction embed not sending

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been attempting to create a Discord bot that plays music and sends an embed to a designated channel displaying the requested song. Unfortunately, the code seems to be malfunctioning. Would you mind taking a look?

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('play')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('song')
                .setDescription('Song name or link!')
                .setRequired(true))
        .setDescription('Plays a desired song!'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const stop = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('stop')
            .setLabel('⏹')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);

        const pause = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('pause')
            .setLabel('⏸')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);

        const play = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('play')
            .setLabel('▶')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);

        const foward = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('foward')
            .setLabel('⏩')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(stop, pause, play, foward);

        let songname = interaction.options.getString('song')
        let guildQueue = client.player.getQueue(interaction.guild.id);
        let queue = client.player.createQueue(interaction.guild.id);

        await queue.join(interaction.member.voice.channel);
        let song = await queue.play(songname).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            if (!guildQueue)
                queue.stop();
        });

        const songembed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("New Song Request!")
            .setDescription(`<a:musicspin:1101029191635447889> ${song.name}`)
            .setFooter({ text: `Requested by <@${interaction.member.id}>`, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL() })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor("Green")

        interaction.reply({ embeds: [songembed], components: [row] });
    }
};
```

And the error

```
DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\pixel\OneDrive\Desktop\NeshayBahs anume waifi\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\pixel\OneDrive\Desktop\NeshayBahs anume waifi\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:736:23)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\pixel\OneDrive\Desktop\NeshayBahs anume waifi\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\pixel\OneDrive\Desktop\NeshayBahs anume waifi\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: undefined,
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: [
          {
            title: 'New Song Request!',
            description: "<a:musicspin:1101029191635447889> FIFTY FIFTY (피프티피프티) - 'Cupid'  Official MV",
            footer: [Object],
            timestamp: '2023-04-27T07:58:25.681Z',
            color: 5763719
          }
        ],
        components: [ { type: 1, components: [Array] } ],
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined,
        thread_name: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1101054714507960340/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTEwMTA1NDcxNDUwNzk2MDM0MDpFaW9MdlA5azd4aWltWjA1QU1scWtQdjFnaDlqMWhFcVJOampjVUVubWVySVhxVmxmYXNUc2JOeXpXUzdsWHVNbVFwQWluTzNtcGJUT2tEMThXS3Y2SUN2SmFNQUpWMkpva2h3RGxPME9nb3BlNkxLTm5BdndDVVlaY2QzNENsdg/callback'
}
```

I've tried using `interaction.deferReply()` and `await interaction.deferReply()` but it doesn't work
Thank you in advance for helping